# Why bodyParser.json() is not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js

I am building an app with Node JS and Express.

In my app I use the following,

```
// middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(express.static('../web'))
app.use(morgan('dev'))
```

above all the `app.get(), app.post()`.

My app goes well when I use Postman. It correctly fetches the data from the back end. But when I am using Google Chrome web browser, the `req.body` in `app.get/post()` is not working. It shows `{}`. That's why I am not able to fetch the data from the db. Front end Angular JS is used.

Request Payload is something like below,[image]

Comment: Probably because you aren't posting JSON … but it is hard to tell because you didn't provide a [mcve] so we can't see how you are constructing the request in Chrome.

Comment: @Quentin: I have put a screenshot.

Comment: Show us an [mcve], not just a picture of your debug tools (which doesn't show all the information I need to test my theories).